# How do I load a page in Codeigniter using JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, post

How would I load a new page to the browser using JQuery whilst posting some data to the new controllers index function?

I was thinking of window.location=url?foo=bar but is there a way to post the data, so that ?foo=bar does not appear in the URL?

Some of the comments suggest using Ajax, but isn't the whole point of ajax that it processes without leaving or refreshing the current page it is running from?

Comment: Why did you mark me down?

Comment: look through the jQuery AJAX API , follow examples  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have looked at that. I want the page I call the post on to redirect to the new page, ajax is not the answer.

Comment: `window.location=url`. Question is not clear what you need

Comment: I was thinking of window.location=url?foo=bar but is there a way to post the data, so that ?foo=bar does not appear in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
   window.location.href
```

it's not possible to send a **POST** request.

What you have to do is to set up a form tag with data fields in it, set the action attribute of the form to the URL and the method attribute to POST, then call the submit method on the form tag.

or you can do the trick by :

Add a form to your HTML, something like this:

```
 <form style="display: hidden" action="/the/url" method="POST" id="form">
   <input type="hidden" id="var1" name="var1" value=""/>
   <input type="hidden" id="var2" name="var2" value=""/>
 </form>
```

and use JQuery to fill these values (of course you can also use javascript to do something similar)

```
 $("#var1").val(value1);
 $("#var2").val(value2);
```

Then finally submit the form

```
 $("#form").submit();
```

on the server side you should be able to get the data you sent by checking var1 and var2, 
for more details refer [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Hope it will help!